# How to not display the full URL in the source

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using the Codeigniter framework I have noticed that when someone visits my site and right-clicks -> view source the entire URL of my file locations and links are displayed.

Currently it is displayed as

```
<link href="http://www.mysite.com/Content/css/ayoba.main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I would like it to display like

```
<link href="/Content/css/ayoba.main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: and why do you need that ??

Comment: You can make the path relative. But what difference does it make? I am trying to understand the scenario where you may need this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with base_url() like

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>Content/css/ayoba.main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('Content/css/ayoba.main.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or

```
<link href="/Content/css/ayoba.main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: `visits my site and right-clicks -> view source `.....are you sure this will change the URL in `view source` ???

Comment: No they will be like http://www.mysite.com/Content/css/ayoba.main.css only...but from my third ans they will be Content/css/ayoba.main.css

Comment: And main thing...you can display the url in any way but when we click on those it will be redirected into your css only

Comment: i wans't the one that downvoted.... anyways what i meant was the thing you said in you 2nd comment.....

Comment: Ok from 3rd you got the ans..??